# tab change thorough jquery script was working, but not working when tab structure changed to responsive-tabs (r-tab structure)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

**tab change thorough jquery script was working, but not working when tab structure changed to responsive-tabs (r-tab structure)**

following jquery statement working properly with regular tab-structure.

But same jquery statement not working when tab structure changed to responsive-tabs (r-tab structure).

**tab change jquery statement:**

```
$('a[href="#fsttab"]').trigger('click');
```

during regular tab-structure, its working properly but when I changed tab structure to responsive-tabs (r-tab structure).. then above jquery statement not working properly.

also tried with following statements but not working:

Try1 (not working):

```
$('a[href="#fsttab"]').click();
```

Try2 (not working):

```
$('a[href="#fsttab"]').responsiveTabs('activate', 1);
```

Try3 (not working):

```
$('a[href="#fsttab"]').tab('show');
```

**I have to change tab through jquery only**.. so please suggest me changes

for information.. screenshot of "responsive-tabs.css" is attached
[image]

Comment: Please post your html as well